# A way to pass a global value to all geometry nodes modifiers in a file?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Let's imagine that many objects in a Blender file / project are using a resolution/density/whatever value.

For example, the 'count' parameter in the 'Fillet curve' node. It would be useful to control that value globally somewhere.

This would make working iteratively on the scene quicker by setting this global value to a low number and then raising it when one wants to render with full details.

Is this something that is possible, and if so, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there are no nodes to pull a property from the current scene and pass it to a geometry node tree. But you should be able to use a driver to the same effect : create a new custom property on the scene (Scene Properties-> Custom Properties), give it the name, type and range you want, right-click on it, *copy as new driver*, then right-click on the property you want to control and *paste driver*. Use the *drivers editor* to change the mapping if necessary.

You'll have to copy and paste the driver on any new object.

Comment: Just tried, it works, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to use a node group:

[image]

Just click on Fillet Curve and make a node group out of it. Unplug the radius and give it whatever radius you like.

Then replace all fillet curve nodes by this node group.

This might be the quicker way if you are adding new fillet curve/node group to your tree because you don't have to add the driver for every node you add.

Comment: This also works, thanks